# My codeigniter site stopped outputting data from my database

Tags: database, codeigniter, validation, content-management-system, dynamic-programming

Good day internet. I am working on a basic cms using codeigniter. I have it set up so it is showing data from my database.

Here is the code in my controller for the first 2 pages

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {
public function index(){
    $this->home();
}

public function home(){
    $this->load->model("model_get");
    $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getData("home");
    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");  
    $this->load->view("content_home", $data);
    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}

public function about(){
$this->load->model("model_get");
    $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getData("about");
    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");  
    $this->load->view("content_about", $data);
    $this->load->view("site_footer");

}
```

Here is the model to get the data from the database

```
class Model_get extends CI_Model{
    function getData($page){
        $query = $this->db->get_where("pageData", array("page" => $page));
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Here is the view to output the data in the database

```
<div id="content">
        <?php  

            foreach($results as $row){
                $title = $row->title;
                $text1 = $row->text1;
                $text2 = $row->text2;                   
            }

            echo heading($title, 1);

        ?>

        <p><?php echo $text1;  ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $text2;  ?></p>
```

It has been working just fine but I wanted to use a form to change the data in the database. Here is the code for the view of my form

```
<div id="content">
<?php

    $this->load->helper("form");

    echo validation_errors();

    echo form_open("site/updatevalues");

    echo form_label("Heading", "title");

    $data = array(
                "name" => "title",
                "id" => "title",
                "value" => set_value("title"),
                "style" => "width:100%",
                "rows" => "rows:3"
            );



    echo form_textarea($data);


    echo form_label("Text 1", "text1");

    $data = array(
                "name" => "text1",
                "id" => "text1",
                "value" => set_value("text1"),
                "style" => "width:100%",
                "rows" => "rows:3"                  
            );

    echo form_textarea($data);

    echo form_label("Text 2: ", "text2");

    $data = array(
                "name" => "text2",
                "id" => "text2",
                "value" => set_value("text2"),
                "style" => "width:100%",
                "rows" => "rows:3"
            );

    echo form_textarea($data);

    echo form_submit("dataSubmit", "Submit");


    echo form_close();

?>
```

Here is the code snippet in my controller that is using the form inputs from the above view

```
public function updatevalues(){
        $this->load->library("form_validation");

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("title", "Heading", "required|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("text1", "Text 1", "required|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("text2", "Text 2", "required|xss_clean");

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $data ["success"] = "";
            $this->load->view("site_header");
            $this->load->view("site_nav");  
            $this->load->view("data_input", $data);
            $this->load->view("site_footer");
        } else {    
            echo $data["success"] = "The page has been updated";
            $this->load->view("site_header");
            $this->load->view("site_nav");  
            $this->load->view("data_input", $data);
            $this->load->view("site_footer");

            $this->load->model("model_update");

            $newRow = array(
                    "id" => "3",
                    "title" => set_value("title"),
                    "page" => "Contact Page",  **<---This was the problem**
                    "text1" => set_value("text1"),
                    "text2" => set_value("text2")
                );

            $this->model_update->update1($newRow);


        }

    }
```

Here is the model that is handling updating the data in the database, I am just using the first function here

```
class Model_update extends CI_Model{
    function update1($data){
    $this->db->update("pagedata", $data, "id = 3");     

    }

    function update2($data){
    $this->db->update_batch("pagedata", $data, "id");
    }

}
```

So after days of trying to figure this out I finally got it to update certain fields in the database which would theoretically update the output in the view but now it is giving me this error message:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: title

Filename: views/content_about.php

Line Number: 10

It is giving the error for all the variables I am trying to echo. I don't get it, I haven't touched the code to display from the database and now that I am finally able to change the data through a form the variable is all of a sudden undefined. If anyone can help me with this I would appreciate it. Been working on this single task for 2 weeks now!

Edit: As I was writing this up I figured out the problem and have put an arrow to identify it. The page data must be "about" because that is how the foreach loop is grabbing the data. I could just not post this but maybe this code will help someone else. Take what you can and enjoy internet you have just witnessed someone correcting themselves, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your site controller function home:

From this:

**$data["results"] = $this->model_get->getData("home");**

Into this:

**$data["results"] = $this->model_get->getData("home page");**

I know this because you took this from the youtube tutorial of Steven.